# Не могу извлечь признаки для обучающей и тестовой выборки

Tags: python, pandas

Ноутбук на Colab https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G-FVwAc-uIGuP2FzoY8YohrrBrAmyrb0
Датасет [hour_online.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HVPWEi6AknmOVBPWheizOG9oI225C3-C/view?usp=sharing). Вот начало этого файла:

> ```
>        Time  Users
> 1/1/17 0:00  34002
> 1/1/17 1:00  37947
> 1/1/17 2:00  41517
> 1/1/17 3:00  44476
> 1/1/17 4:00  46234
> 1/1/17 5:00  48842
> ```

По статье «Открытый курс машинного обучения. Тема 9. [Анализ временных рядов с помощью Python](https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/327242/)» (на Хабр) пытаюсь создать признаки.

По своему тоже не получилось.

Есть БД с датами, которые нужно разбить на обучающие и тестовые выборки
для обучения модели временного ряда. Для этого целевой признак нужно сдвинуть вперед. Подобный подход описан в статье habr.com
Получаем dataset(как в статье)

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('hour_online.csv', index_col=['Time'], parse_dates=['Time'])
```

Далее ошибка на `to_datetime()`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
data.columns = ["y"]

data.index = data.index.to_datetime()
data["hour"] = data.index.hour
data["weekday"] = data.index.weekday
data['is_weekend'] = data.weekday.isin([5,6])*1
data.head()
```

Почему ошибка

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

С учетом ответом о «deprecated index.to_datetime» получила ошибку

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
data.columns = ["y"]

data.index = data.to_datetime()
data["hour"] = data.hour
data["weekday"] = data.weekday
data['is_weekend'] = data.weekday.isin([5,6])*1
data.head()
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Пожалуйста, включите все необходимое в тело вопроса.

Comment: Ваш «Ноутбук на Colab»  - ссылка не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/coursera/hour_online.csv')
data.columns = ["Time","y"]
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])
data["hour"] = data['Time'].dt.hour
data["weekday"] = data['Time'].dt.weekday
data['is_weekend'] = data.weekday.isin([5,6])*1
```

Comment: Я рад, что моя подсказка (даже две) и пример вам помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии Pandas 0.22.x находим 
[в документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) :

```
Index.to_datetime(dayfirst=False)
DEPRECATED: use pandas.to_datetime() instead.
```

А в Pandas 1.0.x *Index.to_datetime*  отсутствует вовсе.

С учетом исправления, внесенного ТС в свой вопрос:

Еще раз, не

```
data.to_datetime()
```

а

```
pd.to_datetime(............)
```

Вот вам готовый работающий ПРИМЕР с результатом:

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
string_date_rng = [str(x) for x in date_rng]
timestamp_date_rng = pd.to_datetime(string_date_rng, 
                                    infer_datetime_format=True)
timestamp_date_rng
Out[6]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 04:00:00', '2018-01-01 05:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 08:00:00', '2018-01-01 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2018-01-07 15:00:00', '2018-01-07 16:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 17:00:00', '2018-01-07 18:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 19:00:00', '2018-01-07 20:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 21:00:00', '2018-01-07 22:00:00',
               '2018-01-07 23:00:00', '2018-01-08 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=169, freq=None)
```